# Error Updating to Ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04 'Failed to lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock'

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, do-release-upgrade

My system said that the upgrade is ready. Did anyone find a solution to this?

I have tried using the `update manager`. But `dist-upgrade` does not even attempt to upgrade and finally I also tried

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

which also fails with following error:

> PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/etc/apt/sources.list'

I tried using `sudo` as well as root (`sudo -i`).

I really don't want to try changing permissions on this file, but if no one else has a solution, then I will try this.

On another post someone said:
Try `sudo apt autoremove`, `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`, but this did not fix the issue either.

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image: Here is a screenshot of the problem.]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)

Comment: Or maybe this question is a more apt duplicate: [Update: Failed to lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock](https://askubuntu.com/q/300269/301745)

Comment: No matter what I do from these and other suggestions, I always ended with the same error "Failed to lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in a similar post.  When I performed the following it worked:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo update-manager -d
```

I ran this once and it required me to reboot. Nothing happened after the reboot so I entered the command `sudo update-manager -d` a second time and it worked.

post where i found the answer: [Ubuntu upgrade failing from 16.04 to 16.10: 'Failed to lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844044/ubuntu-upgrade-failing-from-16-04-to-16-10-failed-to-lock-var-cache-apt-arc) by [toraritte](https://askubuntu.com/users/202663/toraritte)

Answer (score 1):

After reading the entire Internet I found a solution:

$ sudo su

# do-release-upgrade

"sudo su" is important.

Comment: Clever suggestion, but neither that works for me

Comment: Try killall software-SOMETHING